# Why is actor state lost?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am creating an actor service in Azure Service Fabric. When deployed to Azure, it seems to work at first. The texts can be added and returned (the actor is fronted by a Web API), but after some time at idle, GetTextsAsync returns an empty collection.

EDIT:
I have updated the code to check if the state exists before adding it, but it does not solve the problem.

```
[StatePersistence(StatePersistence.Persisted)]
public class TextActor : Actor, ITextActor
{
    protected override async Task OnAactivateAsync()
    {
       if(!await StateManager.ContainsStateAsync("State"))
       {
          await this.StateManager.TryAddStateAsync<List<string>>("State", new List<string>());
       }

    }

    public async Task AddTextAsync(string text)
    {
        var texts = await this.StateManager.GetStateAsync<List<string>>("State");

        texts.Add(text);

        await this.StateManager.SetStateAsync("State", texts);
    }

    public async Task<List<string>> GetTextsAsync()
    {
        return await this.StateManager.GetStateAsync<List<string>>("State");
    }
}
```

EDIT2:
It seems as if the actor itself is replaced. I modified the actor to return its ActorId, and when the list of texts disappear, the ActorId is also replaced with a new.

I am following the pattern in the VoiceMailBox sample, where the actor is created statically in the controller. Is that the problem?

```
public class TextsController : ApiController
{
    private static Uri serviceUri = new Uri("fabric:/TextApp/TextActorService");
    private static ActorId actorId = ActorId.CreateRandom();
    private static ITextActor textActor = ActorProxy.Create<ITextActor>(actorId, serviceUri);        


    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetTexts()
    {
        var texts = await textActor.GetTextsAsync();
        return Ok(texts);            
    }

    //Methods omitted
}
```

Comment: Re Edit 2: The line `private static ActorId actorId = ActorId.CreateRandom();` seems like a bad idea. Each instance of you WebApi stateless service would end up with a different `ActorId`. Even if you only have one instance, if were to be restarted, the replacement instance would have a different `ActorId` for `textActor`. I would have a go at using a constant `ActorId` and see if that solves the issue. Something like `private static ActorId actorId = new ActorId(0);`

Comment: @NickBarrett, that was my main problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the code you have in the `OnActivate()` method - it resets the state to a new list.

The `OnActivate()` method can be called multiple times on an actor - it doesn't only get called when you create a specific actor for the first time. If the actor is not used for a period of time then it gets deactivated (and the `OnDeactivateAsync()` method is called). But when a new call to the actor is made, it is activated again.

It might be worth reading a bit about the actor life cycle https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-lifecycle/

Comment: I have removed the call to OnActivateAsync and instead use StateManager.GetOrAddStateAsync from inside my Get and Add methods. Strangely, the behavior remains.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? If not, it might be worth posting your updated code.

Comment: Not solved, but I have updated the code to reflect my last attempt.

Answer (score 1):

How about instead of using the `OnActivate()` method to initialize your state, you initialize it in your `AddTextAsync(string text)` method as required?

```
public async Task AddTextAsync(string text)
{
    // Try and get the state
    var conditionalTexts = await this.StateManager.TryGetStateAsync<List<string>>("State");
    // If it exists, use it, otherwise create a new one
    List<string> texts = conditionalTexts.HasValue ? conditionalTexts.Value : new List<string>();
    // Make your changes
    texts.Add(text);
    // Save the state
    await this.StateManager.SetStateAsync("State", texts);
}
```

Comment: This is one of many variants I have tested, all still with the same result. The texts disappear after a while.

Comment: Are you using a `List<>` of `string` or a `List<>` of some custom class? If it's a class, then have you set it up with the required `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes?